# ReleaseHold and Get

Tags: evaluation

I've created a `try.m` file which has the following structure:

```
{
  Hold@{a+b+c},
  Hold@{a^2+b^2}
}
```

On my main code I do:

```
Module[{a,b,c,myfile},
   a=1;
   b=2;
   c=3;
   myfile=Get["file.m"];
   ReleaseHold /@ myfile
]
```

note: my desired behavior would be to see the expressions in the file evaluated (linked) to the values of variables in the module. How do I do this?

Dan Reznik

---

my final goal is I have a very long list of algebraic expressions on a,b,c which I want to store in a file and only evaluate when needed.

@Xminer, your solution is not going to work for my case because the expressions will also use variables computed in the Block[] enviroment. I guess Block[] will work.

Comment: try with [`Rule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) and [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html?q=ReplaceAll). `Module[{myfile},
 rule = {a -> 1,
   b -> 2,
   c -> 3};
 myfile = Get["file.m"];
 ReleaseHold /@ myfile //. rule]`

Answer (score 3):

`Module` does not work because it scopes lexically, it replaces symbols like `a` with `a$nnn` then it evaluates the body. It should be clear now that symbols imported after that happened will not be scoped.

You can use `Block` because it scopes dynamically (not by replacing symbols names but by temporarily replacing given symbols definitions).

You can also skip `Hold` in your file.

> { {a+b+c}, {a^2+b^2} }

```
Block[{a = 1, b = 2, c = 3}, Get @ path]
```

Should be enough.